# Deal with an API that changes format

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, codable

Looking for a bit of advice.
I'm tapping into WordsAPI to create a spellchecker iOS app using swift, however, depending on the words you search for the JSON response is sometimes in a different format.

Response for the word "test" looks like this (I've stripped out most of it just to get the point across)

```
{ 
    "word": "test", 
    "pronunciation": {
         "all": "tɛst"
    }
}
```

Whereas the response for the word "testing" looks like this

```
{ 
    "word": "testing", 
    "pronunciation": "'tɛstɪŋ" 
}
```

I'm using a model to decode the response data

```
struct WordDetails: Codable {
   let word: String
   let results: [Definition]
   let pronunciation: Pronounce
}

struct Pronounce: Codable {
   let all: String
}

struct Definition: Codable {
   let definition: String
   let partOfSpeech: String
   let synonyms: [String]?
}
```

But this will only deal with one scenario and fail to decode the other. Can I write it in such a way to deal with both formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the decoding yourself and try to decode pronunciation key as `String` type. If that fails with `DecodingError.typeMismatch` error you decode it as `Pronounce` type:

```
struct WordDetails: Codable {
    let word: String
    let results: [Definition]
    let pronunciation: Pronounce
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case word
        case results
        case pronunciation
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        word = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .word)
        results = try container.decode([Definition].self, forKey: .results)
        do {
            let string = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .pronunciation)
            pronunciation = Pronounce(all: string)
        } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch {
            pronunciation = try container.decode(Pronounce.self, forKey: .pronunciation)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works great. However, I also have a requirement to create a partially empty WordDetail object (with just the word), I then update the details from the API at a later stage. Is this still do-able?

Comment: @jdez you can create a partially empty `WordDetail` object if you change all the properties that you do not need to Optional types or give them default values. I don't know what works best for your case.

Comment: I created a second init, that only takes one parameter and all the others have default values. I think that works ok. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an enum and manually decode the response.

```swift
struct WordDetails: Codable {
   let word: String
   let results: [Definition]
   let pronunciation: PronounceResult
}

struct Pronounce: Codable {
   let all: String
}

enum PronounceResult: Decodable {
    case string(String)
    case object(Pronounce)

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        if let string = try? container.decode(String.self) {
            self = .string(string)
            return
         }
         
         if let pronounce = try? container.decode(Pronounce.self) {
             self = .object(pronounce)
             return
         }
         let context = DecodingError.Context(codingPath: decoder.codingPath,
                                                    debugDescription: "Wrong type")
         throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Value.self, context)
    }
}
```